# subfloat command produces different sized labels

Tags: graphics, subfloats, subfig

I am putting two images side-by-side using the `subfig` package and the `subfloat` command. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[
    labelfont=bf,
    labelformat=parens,
    justification=raggedright,
    position=top,
    ]{caption,subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \subfloat[]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
    }\quad
    \subfloat[]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-golden}%
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which produces this result:

[image: resulting pdf]

The label `(b)` however is noticeably smaller than `(a)` and I have no idea why or how to fix it.

Bonus question: How can I change the labels to use `a)` instead of `(a)`?

Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: As far as the special document class `standalone` is replaced by, for example `article`, size of figure captions is the same. Using `standalone`, I also find adding `\leavevmode` just before the first `\subfloat` seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today is not my day, three times I upload the wrong version of my answer! What an embarrassing !!

Hopefully, now at forth attempt I upload correct version of answer:

**Edit:**
I do not know what is cause of your problem, but remedy for it can be:

- Use of `subcaption`` with own, from caption separated settings (it is not clear, how should be set caption, I assume that caption number is not in parenthesis and that it is followed by colon):

```
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,
            justification=raggedright,
            labelsep=colon,    % <---
            ]{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=brace,  % <---
            singlelinecheck=off,% <---
            position=top,
            ]{subcaption}
```

- use `subfig` which also have own settings, which are the same as at `subcaption`

```
\usepackage[labelformat=brace,% <---
            font=normalsize,
            position=top,
            ]{subfig}
```

In both cases the result is the same:

[image]

Complete MWE is:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont=bf,
            justification=raggedright,
            labelsep=colon,
            ]{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=brace,  %
            singlelinecheck=false,
            position=top,
            ]{subcaption}       % or subfig

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\hfil
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-golden}}
%
\caption{Figure caption}
\label{fig:??}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: almost - if I use `caption, subcaption`, the size is right, but there is the extra bracket and colon around `(a):` but in your bonus answer, the `a)` looks good, but `b)` is too small again.

Comment: @JohnSmith, you are right. Please check edited answer. Now it should be such as you want to be :-)

Answer (score 2):

`\subfloat` is also supported by subcaption.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[
    labelfont=bf,
    labelformat=brace,
    labelsep=space,
    justification=raggedright,
    position=top,
    ]{caption,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \subfloat[]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
    }\quad
    \subfloat[]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-golden}%
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]